# Hibernate/JPA: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables Friendship and User. What I was trying to do is establish the friendship relation with already existing users.

```
@Entity(name = "friendship")
public class Friendship {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8950073132358183472L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "requester_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User requester;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User receiver; 

}

@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requester")
    private Set<Friendship> requesterFriendships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
    private Set<Friendship> requestedFriendships;

}

public class FriendshipServiceImpl implements FriendshipService {

    @Autowired
    FriendshipRepository friendshipRepository;

    public Friendship save(Friendship friendship) {

        return friendshipRepository.save(friendship);
    }


    public Friendship requestFriendship(User requester, User receiver) {
        Friendship friendship = new Friendship(requester, receiver, LocalDateTime.now(), FriendshipStatus.REQUESTED);
        return save(friendship);
    }
}
```

**Calling Controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addFriend(@PathVariable("id") long id, Principal principal) {
    User requester = userService.getUserByUsername(principal.getName());
    User receiver = userService.getUser(id);

    if (requester != null && receiver != null) {
        friendshipService.requestFriendship(requester, receiver);
    }

    return "friendsManagement";
}
```

FriendshipRepository extends Spring data CrudRepository. Now when I try to save I get the following error. The requesters and receivers User object are already existing object. Help me understand this error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/sample-app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist(); nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()] with root cause
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:95)
```

Comment: Post the method that calls `requestFriendship()`

Comment: @prettyvoid I have updated the calling controller method.

Comment: Your mapping is realy weird. It's more common that @OneToMany own the relation. Here it's the opposite. I'll change that if i were you.

Comment: Post the code for UserService and its implementation and the UserDao

Comment: There is no Dao. Its Spring data CrudRepository.

Comment: Why don't you paste the code inside `getUserByUsername()` and `getUser()` from the service class.